# How to link audio file and autoplay

Tags: javascript, html

I have an audio visualizer that creates audio waves based on the inputed music file. The file has to manually be put into the "choose file" area. How do I make it so that I can simply link a pr-existing file, so that when the page loads, it immediately starts playing audio.mp3

Here is the code that Im working with:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var audio,
      analyser,
      audioContext,
      sourceNode,
      stream;

  var svg = document.getElementById('svg'),
      svgNS = svg.namespaceURI,
      g = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "g");

  var width = window.innerWidth,
      height = window.innerHeight,
      maxHeight = Math.max(height * 0.3, 300),
      fftSize = 512, // 512
      tilt = 40,
      choke = 110,
      c = 0;

  var audioInput = document.getElementById('audiofile');

  // choose file
  audioInput.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    stream = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = stream;
    setup();
  });

  function setup() {
    audio.addEventListener('canplay', function () {
      document.body.className+='loaded';
      audioContext = new AudioContext();
      analyser = (analyser || audioContext.createAnalyser());
      analyser.minDecibels = -90;
      analyser.maxDecibels = -10;
      analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 1;//0.75;
      analyser.fftSize = fftSize;

      sourceNode = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio);
      sourceNode.connect(analyser);
      sourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

      audio.play();
      update();
    });
  }

  function shape(g, freqValue, freqSequence, freqCount, colorSequence) {
    var freqRatio = freqSequence/freqCount,
        x = (width - (tilt * 2)) * freqRatio + tilt,
        y = height / 2;

    var polyline = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "polyline"),
        // using power to increase highs and decrease lows
        freqRatio = freqValue / 255,
        throttledRatio = (freqValue - choke) / (255 - choke),
        strokeWidth = width / freqCount * 0.6 * throttledRatio,
        throttledY = Math.max(throttledRatio, 0) * maxHeight,
        // color
        color = "hsl(" +
          ((freqSequence / 2) + Math.floor(colorSequence)) + ", " +
          100 + "%," +
          freqRatio * 80 + "%" +
        ")";

    var loc_x = x - strokeWidth / 2,
        loc_y1 = y - throttledY / 2,
        loc_y2 = y + throttledY / 2,
        x_offset = tilt * throttledRatio;

    if (throttledRatio > 0) {
      var point_1 = (loc_x - x_offset) + "," + loc_y1,
          point_2 = (loc_x + x_offset) + "," + loc_y2;
      var points = [ point_1, point_2 ];
    } else {
      var points = [loc_x + "," + (y-1),loc_x + "," + (y+1)]
    }

    polyline.setAttribute("stroke-width", strokeWidth);
    polyline.setAttribute("stroke", color);
    polyline.setAttribute("points", points.join(" "));
    g.appendChild(polyline);
  }

  svg.setAttribute("width", width+"px");
  svg.setAttribute("height", height+"px");
  svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height);
  svg.appendChild(g);

  function update() {
    g.remove();
    g = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "g");
    var freqArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(freqArray);

    for (var i = 0; i < freqArray.length; i++) {
      var v = freqArray[i];
      shape(g, v, i+1, freqArray.length, c);
    }
    svg.appendChild(g);

    c += 0.5;
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
  }
};

jakealbaughSignature("light");
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
}

body.loaded input {
  display: none;
}

#svg {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
#svg polyline {
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

```html
<input id=audiofile type=file>
<svg id=svg></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Autoplay of audio is disabled on most browsers.  There *must* be some user interaction, and you can only start playback on that user interaction, such as a click event.

Comment: Thats fine, is there way to make it just a button press?

Comment: @Joe Sure, just onclick, `audio.play()` is all that's needed.

Comment: Do you mind making the change on my code, im having a bit of difficulty :(

Comment: I think I may not be understanding the question.  You wrote all of this code and are having trouble with a click handler?

Comment: No actually I found it on codepen, im just trying to make a demo